# Change the background image of Div A on hover of Div B using only CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

> This is what i am having

Four Buttons on home page inside a Main Div with background image.

> What i want to achieve

On hover of each button i want to change the background image using only **`CSS`**.

I can the **`HTML`** markup to some extent.

Below is prototype

**My HTML**

```
<div id="mainImage"><img class="style1" width="100%" height="100%"  /></div>
<div id="DwellRestBtn"><a href="Dwell & Rest.html">Four</a></div>
<div id="DwellRestBtn"><a href="Dwell & Rest.html">Three</a></div>
<div id="DwellRestBtn"><a href="Dwell & Rest.html">Two</a></div>
<div id="DwellRestBtn"><a href="Dwell & Rest.html">One</a></div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.style1
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

.style1
{
content:url('http://www.audenaerde.org/tiger.jpg');
}
a:hover .style1
{
content:url('http://www.butterflypictures.net/images/morpho-butterfly.jpg');
}
```

If there is method with `css3` its should be compatibilty with atleast modern browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have multiple elements with the same ID attribute, which is supposed to be unique. I've changed it into classes.
2. As far as I know, with the current CSS you can do what you want if the image is following the buttons (but not preceding them), however you can still make the image visually precede the buttons (but not in the DOM). Then you can use the [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Sdcts/)

```
.DwellRestBtn:hover ~ #mainImage .style1
{
    background: url('http://www.butterflypictures.net/images/morpho-butterfly.jpg');
}
```